# Refresh cached dataframe?

Tags: apache-spark

We have a small hive table (around 50000 records) which is updated once, daily.

We have a cached Data-frame for this table and is being joined with spark streaming data. How do we refresh the data frame when new data is loaded in base hive?

```
DataFrame tempApp = hiveContext.table("emp_data");

//Get Max Load-Date
Date max_date =  max_date = tempApp.select(max("load_date")).collect()[0].getDate(0);

//Get data for latest date and cache. This will be used to join with stream data.
DataFrame emp= hiveContext.table("emp_data").where("load_date='" + max_date + "'").cache();

// Get message from Kafka Stream
JavaPairInputDStream<String, String> messages  = KafkaUtils.createDirectStream(....);

JavaDStream<MobileFlowRecord> rddMobileFlorRecs = messages.map(Record::parseFromMessage);

kafkaRecs.foreachRDD(rdd->{DataFrame recordDataFrame = hiveContext.createDataFrame(rdd, Record.class);

DataFrame  joinedDataSet = recordDataFrame.join(emp, 
recordDataFrame.col("application").equalTo(app.col("emp_id"));
joinedDataSet. <Do furthur processing>
});
```

Comment: check this link. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66911985/spark-structured-streaming-batch-data-refresh-issue-partition-by-clause/67808282#67808282

Answer (score 3):

You can do it manually. Something like this:

```
DataFrame refresh(DataFrame orig) {
    if (orig != null) {
        orig.unpersist();
    }
    DataFrame res = get the dataframe as you normally would
    res.cache()
    return res
```

Now call this once a day or whenever you wish to refresh like this:

```
   DataFrame join_df = refresh(join_df)
```

What this basically does is unpersists (removes caching) of a previous version, reads the new one and then caches it. So in practice the dataframe is refreshed.

You should note that the dataframe would be persisted in memory only after the first time it is used after the refresh as caching is lazy.

Answer (score 2):

Spark Automatically `unpersist` the RDD or Dataframe if they are no longer used. In order to know if a RDD or Dataframe is cached, you can get into the Spark UI -- > Storage tabl and see the Memory details. You can use `df.unpersist()` or `sqlContext.uncacheTable("sparktable")` [uncacheTable APi](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SQLContext@uncacheTable(tableName:String):Unit) to remove the df or tables from Memory.This option is not available in new [SparksessionAPi](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.SparkSession) but backward compatibility is always there. Spark made for Lazy Evaluation, unless and until you say any action, it does not load or process any data into the RDD or DataFrame.

So for you After performing the `join` do the [unpersist()](https://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.sql.Dataset@unpersist():Dataset.this.type) for your Dataframe. Which will increase the performance and as well as solve your problem .

[Databricks](https://forums.databricks.com/questions/8087/when-will-rdd-cache-will-get-expired.html)

Comment: I doubt if I understood your solution. Caching and uncaching dataset may solve problem but it defeats the purpose of caching, as cache is valid only for one iteration only. I have added the sample code for more clarification.  Secondly, i tested, caching and uncaching on each iteration is adding around 3 sec delay.   Wondering if there is any other way to achieve this ?